# android onNewIntent Synchronization

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have a `MainActivity` and a `Service`.
I started my APP.
Then I put it to background.
I opened a ES file explorer, select a file, and click to open with my APP.

In my APP, I implemented `onNewIntent()` to handle intent from ES file explorer. In `onNewIntent()`, I broadcase the file name to service.

The observation is (by putting log message in `onCreate()`, `onNewIntent()`, `onStartCommand()`):

The activity is restarted. I see onCreate() is called.

In `onCreate()` I started the `Service`.

I then see the called of `onNewIntent()`.

However, the service does not start up fast enough to handle the intent of `onNewIntent()`, so I did not get the filename.

What is wrong with my logic? or what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u set this in android manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.

Comment: i used android:launchMode="singleTask" before. I now changed to "singleInstance". I still see onCreate() is called. The whole flow is the same, but with addition of broadcasting log. So it works. BUT it cause another bug. I have another activity and have StartActivityResult and OnActivityResult. By using singleInstance, another activity is never started and OnActivityResult immediately  returned with null intent. why? thanks